# Simpleconfig using default application name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know how to set default application name and available locales on simple config. Could you help me on how to do? What I'm trying is

```
SimpleConfig.for :application do
  set "My_application"

  set :available_locales
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this configuration

```
SimpleConfig.for :application do
  set :app_name, 'your_applicaiton_name'
  set :available_locales, Hash[{ :en => 'English (US)', :tr => 'Your_Language' }.sort_by { |_, native_name| native_name }]
```